# Rewrite File With Condition (If Elseif Else) Htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have file image.php at my root folder, it's function to compress image and manipulate path

So, default to use is `image.php?width=100&height=100&ratio=1:1&watermark=watermark.png&src=image.png`

How to rewrite :

1. `domain.com/image/100/100/image.png` (width, height, src)
2. `domain.com/image/100/100/1:1/image.png` (width, height, ratio, src)
3. `domain.com/image/100/100/1:1/watermark.png/image.png` (width, height,
       ratio, watermark, src)

To solved first condition i have rewrite look like this one :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^image/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /image.php?width=$1&height=$2&src=$3 [QSA,L]
```

But i don't know how to solved other condition, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use 3 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^image/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$                 /image.php?width=$1&height=$2&src=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^image/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$         /image.php?width=$1&height=$2&ratio=$3&src=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^image/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /image.php?width=$1&height=$2&ratio=$3&watermark=$4&src=$5 [QSA,L]
```

If it catch the first rule, the second and the third won't be executed (thanks to the `[L]` tag, which stop .htaccess execution on catch).